# How to get user based and tag based photos from instagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, instagram, instafeedjs

I have a requirement where i have to show instagram photos  from  users account `xxxx` and photos tagged as `x,x2,x3,x4`.

Is it possible to do to both user account based and tagged based photos in with instafeed.js script

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/markmurray/pen/dtseB?editors=001)

Script

```
var instaFeed = new Instafeed({
                    get: 'user',
                    userId: 6678174,
                    accessToken: '6678174.467ede5.205a03ebc4b74d4082823781c3149575',
                    target: 'instafeed',
                    sortBy: 'most-recent',
                    limit: 32,
                    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
  template: '<a class="fancybox" href="{{image}}"><img src="{{image}}" /><div id="filter">{{model.filter}}</div><div class="info"><p class="location"><i class="icon-location"></i>{{location}}</p><p><i class="icon-comment"></i>{{caption}}</p><br><ul><li class="icon-heart">{{likes}} likes<li class="icon-chat">{{comments}} comments</ul></div></a>'
}).run();

$.fn.extend({
  matchHeight: function(data){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(this).each(function() {
       maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
    });
   $(this).height(maxHeight);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no single API that will allow you to do both user and hashtag search.

You can use the user/media API to get photos and manually check for the hashtag in `tags` of each photo in API response

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

http://gramfeed.com has implemented this, search and open a user page on gramfeed, scroll and load all photos, and then use the `filter by keyword` to filter photos with an hashtag

Comment: instafeed also has a option where one can get photos based on user and then filters the same photos based on tags. `var feed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'user',
  userId: USER_ID,
  filter: function(image) {
    return image.tags.indexOf('TAG_NAME') >= 0;
  }
});
feed.run();`